# Does too much Genetical Modification leads to formation of new species?

Tags: speciation

I think Genetical Modification can be termed as 'Artificial Mutation'.
Is it possible that genes can be modified so much that it leads to the introduction of new Species i.e Can integration of large no. of Helpful mutations lead to quick evolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it possible, in one [article](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/270/5235/397.long) show a study for Mycoplasma genitalium which have 525 gene, however only 382 genes are essential for biological functions, they take out the nature gene and place the ' artifical gene' which synthsis in vitro, to test if the M. genitalium will survival when the No. of gene lower than 382. If it survival it will be a new species.

Comment: Can you please add some references to your answer? Actually it is more a comment.

Comment: What article are you talking about?

Comment: I think it is Mycoplasma laboratorium. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycoplasma_laboratorium

Comment: yep, Mycoplasma laboratorium is the thing I talk about which is genetic modifacation product of  M. genitalium